# 16.04 - login in loop after logout

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, dell

I have the following issue: the first log in works as intended. If I log out and log in again I am stuck in a loop and I have to reboot. I am using the nvidia drivers 364. The machine is an inspiron 7559 with a 4k screen.

Please advise